# Symfony Doctrine perform a leftJoin and get all results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 2, I have this query, and I want to get all the names  of contacts of all users:

```
$results = $es->createQueryBuilder()
->select('m.id, d.contactName')
->from('AppBundle:Profile', 'm')
->leftJoin('AppBundle:Contacts', 'd','with','d.profileid = m.id')
->groupBy('m.id')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Problem is that, when I want to display the name of the contacts per user, I only get one name. I could use a for loop on each user, but I cannot use that at the moment. I want to be able to display all names without looping

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add the code you have to your question. Also, add how you're currently displaying the data, how the output looks like and how the output should look like instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that `Profile` and `Contacts` are connected with some sort of relation, but you still use `profileid` to enforce that relationship - this is totally obsolete.

As for the single result being returned, I think you use the `groupBy` the wrong way, but I cannot tell for sure without seeing the entities in play.

Regardless, in this situation I would definitely for for `getArrayResult()` function (instead of `getResult()`), which will return, well, array. Try also removing the `groupBy` and seeing what you get.

I can expand my answer once you update your question with entities.